# What station (and shuttle) did Scott Parker see in Prey (2017)?

Tags: prey

There is a note in the Shuttle Bay that says:

> Earth liftoff was at 0900. Conditions nominal. Pre-check certified. 4 executive passengers. Mail cargo.
>
>  Flight was uneventful until 1133 when radar detected an unidentified shuttle approximately thirty degrees off our flight path at 9,000 km. Its drift and rotation indicated malfunctioning maneuvering thrusters. There was no answers to radio calls. Captain Cooper ordered a course adjustment to bring us alongside.
>
>  As we maneuvered to within 60km, a second shuttle appeared on radar in the vicinity of the drifting vessel. Transponders identified it as a military vessel. We received a radio message to resume our original heading immediately. Captain Cooper asked if assistance was required and the order from the military shuttle was repeated.
>
>  All highly unusual, but then it got really strange. The captain spotted it first. There was a facility out there and it was running absolutely dark. No lights. Radar transparent. We were too far to see any details, but it was big. Cooper snapped into action, punched in a course to Talos and fired the engines. We moved out as quickly as possible.
>
>  Our passengers were clueless to the entire encounter. Our arrival at Talos went by smoothly and the passengers and cargo were delivered safely.

What station did he see? And what about the shuttle? It is not the one that's floating outside of Talos I as it is identified by another subplot.

Comment: IIRC, the distressed shuttle is the same one you visit in game. The other station would presumably be where Dahl is based.

Comment: No, the one you visit is the Advent, we know its origin.